# patching a local instance

Tags: python, monkeypatching

consider I have the following code in python module `a.py`:

```
def func():
    obj = Obj()
    # Some code that uses obj
```

Is there a way to monkey patch `obj` without making it a function argument?

**Reason:** In the context of the code itself it should not be an argument, however in the context of testing and system simulations using the code, the patch is reasonable. Also in various scenarios I may need to patch different local objects and placing all of them as arguments would be tedious.

Comment: You're probably over-complicating it, take a look at inversion of control principle. I'm still interested how can this be achieved in Python.

Comment: probably :)  although the application is complicated to start with so I have somewhat of an excuse... I'd still like to know how this monkeypatching can be done, and it can save me lots of work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# if func() is defined in `a.py`
import a

oldObj, a.Obj = a.Obj, MockObj
a.func()
a.Obj = oldObj
```

Comment: So what he says is: import module with your function and monkey-patch the class , not variable.

Comment: oh... but what if I need this patch only in a certain function and not throughout `a.py`?

Comment: @Jonathan: After the call to `a.func()` you could restore `a.Obj` to previous value.

Comment: I'll just add: if `a.func()` is used internally in `a` then one could `import a` then set `a.func = local_func` and have `local_func` perform: 1) override `a.Obj` 2) call the original `a.func` 3) restore `a.Obj`